# Problems with malloc and realloc

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, free, calloc

Why do I get 0 bytes after a block of size 7 alloc'd error when I am still leaving space for `'\0'`?

I tried allocating and reallocating 7 bytes and kept the size variable going up by 5 so that there would always be at least 2 bytes left at the end when I add the null terminator, but I am still getting the valgrind error:

> Invalid write of size 1:
>
> 0 bytes after a block of size 7 alloc'd

whenever I read or write to token, for example I get it on this line:

```c
token[i] = read;
```

```c
void parse_file(char file[]) {

    char read = 0;
    int size = 5;
    char *token = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    token = malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: No such file or directory\n", file);
        free(token);
        fclose(fp);
        return;
    }
    read = fgetc(fp);
    while(read != EOF) {
        if(i == size) {
            token = realloc(token, 7 * sizeof(char));
            size += 5;
        }
        if(isalpha(read)) {
            read = (char) tolower(read);
            token[i] = read;
        }
        else {
            if(isalpha(token[0])) {
                token[i] = '\0';
                put(token);
            }
            else {
                free(token);
            }
            token = calloc(7,sizeof(char));
            size = 5;
            i = 0;
            read = fgetc(fp);
            continue;
        }
        read = fgetc(fp);
        i++;
    }
    free(token);
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Compile it with `-g` and execute it again with valgrind. It will tell you which line is causing the trouble, so this helps to narrow down the problem. It is hard to read code, try to interpret what you want to do and find a bug simultaneously.

Comment: you"re allocating only 7 bytes for `token`, with 3 different methods. realloc doesn't _add_ bytes. it sets the block size to the value you're passing, not the value+old value

Comment: Aside: `char read` ==> `int readed` for two reasons: a) `fgetc` returns `int` as do most similar functions. b) `read` is a library function, it is not good to duplicate identifiers, even when they have a different context.

Comment: It always is a good idea to explain what the code posted (at least roughly) ought to do.

Comment: there is the well known function: `read()`.  It is poor programming practice to use the same name for local variables as the C library function name.s

Comment: there is no function named `put()`, so what are you expecting this statement: `put(token);` to do.  As it is, the posted code does not compile, even after adding the missing `#include` statements

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression from the call to `malloc()`, etc

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "%s: No such file or directory\n", file);`  this is outputting to the correct I/O stream, but is missing the text from the system, that indicates why the system thinks the operation failed.  Suggest using: `perror()`

Comment: When calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when calling `realloc()`, always assign the result to a temp variable, then check that variable and only if the operation was successful, then assign the temp variable to the target variable.

Comment: regarding: `token = realloc(token, 7 * sizeof(char));`  this is only allocating 7 bytes total, not an additional 7 bytes.  Suggest: `char *temp = realloc(token, 7+size ); if( !temp ) { perror( "realloc failed" );  free( token );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  }  //implied else, realloc successful:  token = temp;`

Comment: right after the call to `realloc()` is the statement: `size += 5;`   Each time this loop is executed, the variable `size` falls 2 more bytes behind the actual number of bytes allocated.  Suggest adding the same number of bytes as the additional allocation

Comment: regarding: `put(token);`   maybe you meant: `puts(token);`

Comment: Regarding the function: `tolower()`  This has absolutely not effect on non alphabetic characters.  So no need to test using the first call to `isalpha()`

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. eliminates unnecessary code/logic
3. performs the desired functionality
4. properly checks for errors
5. incorporates the comments to the OPs question
6. incorporates the comments to this answer

and now the proposed code: (EDITED)

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, realloc(), free()
#include <stdio.h>    // FILE, fprintf(),  fopen(), fgetc(), perror()
#include <ctype.h>    // isalpha(), tolower()
#include <errno.h>    // errno
#include <string.h>   // strerror()


// prototypes
void parse_file(char fileName[]);


void parse_file(char fileName[])
{

    int byteRead = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    char *token = NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;


    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if( !fp )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s: %s\n", fileName, strerror(errno));
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    while( (byteRead = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        char *temp = NULL;

        if(i >= size)
        {
            temp = realloc(token, 7 + size );
            if( !temp )
            {
                perror( "realloc failed" );
                free( token );
                fclose( fp );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, realloc successful

            size += 7;
            token = temp;
        }

        if( isalpha(byteRead) )
        {
            byteRead = tolower(byteRead);
            token[i] = (char)byteRead;
            i++;
        }

        else if( i )
        {
            token[i] = '\0';

            puts(token);
            free( token );

            i = 0;
            size = 0;
        }
    }

    free(token);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: An error message for a failing `fopen` should include the filename that couldn't be opened. I suggest `fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s: %s\n", file, strerror(errno));`.

Comment: `token = temp;` is an error: `temp` is not in scope.

Comment: `if (isalpha(read)) { ... } if (!isalpha(read) ...` is redundant: You can just use `else`.

Comment: I haven't thought it through completely, but I think there might be a use-after-free bug in your logic.